# Decompile a PerlApp Exe from ten years ago

Tags: perl, perl-module, decompiler, activestate, perlapp

I am asking something a little obsolete. I retrieved one of my project written back more than 10 years ago, when I was a student, but unfortunately I could only retrieve the executable.
I am trying to decompile it, but I really cannot recall the Perl version at the time, I remember only that I used PerlApp, and Perl was ActiveState Perl.
If you want, no problem updating the 500 kb executable, I am not gelous of my kid-me-work, I just whish I could see how moron of a programmer I was :)

Thanks in advance

Matteo

Comment: If it's anything like the standalone executables PAR::Packer generates, it's not actually compiled---just bundled. Try extracting the file with an unzip utility.

Comment: no, unfortunately it is an exe and it is not just compressed :(

Comment: Some people had success with this process; http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=A%20real%20challenge